# Capistrano assets error: Errno::EMLINK: Too many links @ dir_s_mkdir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I am having an issue with my current capistrano deployments of my rails application.

```
Errno::EMLINK: Too many links @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/travelninja/app_staging/releases/20160726161529/tmp/cache/assets/production/sass/34b38f7adaaf169bd78016fa78239bdc16903911
  (in /home/travelninja/app_staging/releases/20160726161529/app/assets/stylesheets/admin.scss)
/home/travelninja/app_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/cache/file_store.rb:25:in `[]='
/home/travelninja/app_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:34:in `cache_set'
/home/travelninja/app_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.3/lib/sass/rails/cache_store.rb:13:in `_store'
/home/travelninja/app_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/cache_stores/base.rb:51:in `store'
/home/travelninja/app_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/engine.rb:417:in `_to_tree'
/home/travelninja/app_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/engine.rb:281:in `render'
/home/travelninja/app_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.3/lib/sass/rails/template.rb:47:in `evaluate'
/home/travelninja/app_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
/home/travelninja/app_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
/home/travelninja/app_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
/home/travelninja/app_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
/home/travelninja/app_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
/home/travelninja/app_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
```

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that our staging server never cleared the cache folder. It was symlinked on every deployment. There were many files inside. After clearing it worked nicely.

Comment: The issue can be recreated by going to each folder, eg `cd /home/travelninja/app_staging/releases/20160726161529/tmp/cache/assets/production/sass` and trying to create one more directory with `mkdir test`. So this command tells: `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: Too many links`